# How to split the single column to multiple column in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

with the below expression to extract circuit,it is handling correclty. regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\s([a-zA-Z0-9 [] \& ]+)(,\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit", But I found this scenario where circuit is showing null becuase of parenthesis-->Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Financial Wire (self-service), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' this scenario not getting handled in circuit.

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output and show your attempt as per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, pasted the desired output, I am using Regex_substr, still missing something

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job using [regexp_substr](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)

```
SELECT
 regexp_substr(base_string, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Cir",
 regexp_substr(base_string, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Language",
 regexp_substr(base_string, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words"
FROM values
  ('Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: OTC Specialty New York Metro, Language(s): English, Words: 1944'),
  ('Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English, Words: 46'),
  ('Attachment(s): 3, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 117')
AS my_table(base_string)
;
```

Comment: Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English, Words: 46
this code is working fine, but in some case like below exmple:

Attachments: 1, Language: English, Words: 400 -- language is showing null instead of English

Comment: Thats's because the regex used here relies on the key names you provided.
e.g : Circuit / Language(s) / Words

Are you key names subject to change from one record to another ?
For example : Language(s) -> Language

Comment: How to achieve that case, please provide your inputs. I have the data in the two ways for that column. Language(s):/ Language:

Comment: Well if you want to match Language or Language(s) you can use this regex : regexp_substr(base_string, 'Language(\\(s\\)|):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) AS "Language".

But in my opinion your input keys should be consistant (should not change between records).

Comment: Sorry to say, appreciate your efforts, the code regexp_substr(base_string, 'Language(\(s\)|):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) AS "Language" displaying the null values for all the scenarios.

Comment: Tested with your examples and outputs looks OK (no null anywhere) :

SELECT
 regexp_substr(base_string, 'Language(\\(s\\)|):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) AS "Language"
FROM values
  ('Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: OTC Specialty New York Metro, Language(s): English, Words: 1944'),
  ('Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English, Words: 46'),
  ('Attachment(s): 3, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 117'),
  ('Attachments: 1, Language: English, Words: 400')
AS my_table(base_string)
;

Comment: May be i am missing something, still showing null. tried to attach the screenshot, unable to do so.

Comment: with the below expression to extract circuit,it is handling correclty. regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\]  \\& ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit", 
But I found this scenario where circuit is showing null becuase of parenthesis-->Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Financial Wire (self-service), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' this scenario not getting handled in circuit.